# PHPUnit code coverage in NetBeans fails with Yaml dependency

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I am trying to get the code coverage in NetBeans working, but I am stuck on error that the PHPUnit gives me:

```
"/usr/bin/php" "/usr/bin/phpunit" "--colors" "--log-junit" "/tmp/nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--bootstrap" "/home/btekielski/Dokumenty/Projects/PlanQ/src/tests/bootstrap.php" "--coverage-clover" "/tmp/nb-phpunit-coverage.xml" "/usr/local/netbeans-7.4/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php" "--run=/home/btekielski/Dokumenty/Projects/PlanQ/src/tests"
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning' with message 'include_once(Symfony/Component/Yaml/Yaml.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /home/user/Projects/src/tests/bootstrap.php:65
Stack trace:
```

I have a custom auto loader function in bootstrap which looks like following:

```
function loadClass($class) {
    if (empty($class) || $class == 'parent') {
        return;
    }
    $throw = false;

    if (strpos($class, 'PHPExcel') !== false) {
        return;
    }

    $file = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class) . CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION;
    include_once($file);

    if (!class_exists($class, false) && !interface_exists($class, false)) {
        if ($throw) {
            trigger_error(
                    "Class file '" . $file . "' do not provide class '" .
                    $class . "'", E_USER_ERROR
            );
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any hints...

Comment: Is your PHPUnit using the loader via the bootstrap or configuration in NetBeans?

Comment: via the bootstrap.php.

Comment: The include_once() you called has a relative path to Symphony, indicating it is below the current directory.  Is this the case, or are you in the wrong directory for this relative path to work?

Comment: That was it, I updated bootstrap to include vendor path (from composer) and it's working fine. Thanks!

Comment: Moving to the answer then so you can accept, and others can find the thread easier if they have the same problem.  Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include_once() you called has a relative path to Symphony, indicating it is below the current directory. Is this the case, or are you in the wrong directory for this relative path to work?